# Unable to find a column in sqlite 3 database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I saved my data in databse where I created two columns with master_user and master_password.I inserted a value in my database. But somehow I am unable to find that master_user with my current code. **error-** sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: animesh7370

```
def login(self):
   

    conn = sqlite3.connect("master.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    #conn.execute("CREATE TABLE master_database (master_users TEXT NOT #NULL,master_password 
                                                                              #TEXT NOT NULL)")
    #cur.execute("INSERT INTO master_database (master_users,master_password) 
                                                            #VALUES('animesh7370','A@singh7')")

    user =  self.root.ids.user.text
    password = self.root.ids.password.text
    print(type(password))
    cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM master_database WHERE master_user = {user}")
    #cur.execute("SELECT * FROM  master_database  ")
    c=cur.fetchone()
    for items in c:
     print(items)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Please don't use string formatting in queries.  Use the solutions in the duplicate to your [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519681/sqlite-where-query-giving-error-with-some-issue-with-placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

Naming problem. You forgot the 's' to `master_user`.

```
cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM master_database WHERE master_users = {user}")
                                                      HERE --^
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error - sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This is because your resulting SQL looks like this (assuming that user is `'animesh7370'`):

```sql
SELECT * FROM master_database WHERE master_user = animesh7370
```

Better use command parameters

```py
select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM master_database WHERE master_users = %s"
cur.execute(select_stmt, (user,))
```

Note that command parameters are not simply inserted as a string concatenation but are passed to the query with the appropriate data type.

See: [Passing parameters to SQL queries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

You declared the column as `master_users` but referred to it as `master_user` in the select statement. It is usual to use column names in singular.

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM master_database WHERE master_users =?" ,(user,))
```